# Running X-CTU on linux

Tags: linux, xbee

I am trying to X-CTU running on linux under wine so I can apply firmware to my Xbee radio.  The program install and runs fine under wine but when I go to the Modem Configuration tab it errors out saying it can't read my modem configuration.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working.  You have to download all the firmware updates from the Digi site (ftp://ftp1.digi.com/support/firmware/).  The files you need are:

```
82001817_a.zip
82001817_B.zip
82001817_C.zip
82001817_D.zip
82001817_E.zip
82001817_F.zip
82001817_G.zip
```

Download the above files into:

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Digi/XCTU/update
```

Then open X-CTU and go to the modem configuration tab.  Click the Download new versions button then select from file.  Select each of the files you downloaded.  Once you have the all loaded click the read configuration button and this time it should work.